# Why can't users besides root create files in a samba share?

Tags: permissions, mount, samba

I am sharing a directory on one Red Hat machine via samba, and mounting it on another Red Hat machine with the following command:

```
mount -t cifs -o guest <remotepath> <localpath>
```

The smb.conf file on the host is set up to allow the guest user to write and create files.  However, the root user can freely create files in the mounted share, and but when other users attempt to create a file, they get a "Permission denied" error.  What's the story?  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you check the posix acl of the folder? (selinux too if enabled)

Comment: Thanks, good question.  The ACL appears to be set correctly, and SELinux is disabled.

Comment: And what are the current posix permissions of the directory?